# django gives an error __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, rss, feed

error is here:
    /data/http/cobalt/cards/urls.py in

```
106:    (r'^latest/feed', LatestNews()) ...
```

this part of urls.py which throw an error

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from myproject.feeds import LatestNews

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    # ...
    (r'^latest/feed/$', LatestNews()),
    # ...
```

)

Actually I have copied all code from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/syndication/

but url they provide has mistake which i am not able to locate

Comment: Please post the actual exception in full.

Comment: You link to the 1.1 documentation, but your code seems to come from the rewritten version in 1.2 or later - can you confirm which version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

In LatestNews, you are probably using

```
from django.contrib.syndication.feeds import Feed
```

instead of

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
```

Answer (score 0):

The error must be with `LatestNews`. You are passing no arguments, meaning that it will receive one (the object itself). `LatestNews` is the only object being constructed on that line (the URL is a simple tuple, which has no fixed number of arguments).

Check the `LatestNews` class - its `__init__()` method no doubt takes three arguments.

Comment: LatestNews is subclass of Feed and can be found on same page, just instead of class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed): i have class LatestNews(Feed)

Comment: @user1262187 Subclasses can have different number of arguments to their constructor in Python. Are you *sure* that it doesn't have `__init__()` defined differently?

Comment: code of my LatestNews can be found on page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/?from=olddocs. under Simple Example paragraph. I have the same class just instead of LatestNewsFeed i have LatestNews.

Comment: and one more if error is in LatestNews class then exception should happen in case if my url ends with latest/news, but it fails even in case if i open root localhost

Comment: @user1262187 The LatestNews object is created when the literal is parsed, meaning that it is created on any page, not just when that URL is visited.

Comment: @user1262187 If this is not the error, then please post the exception in full as Python gives it to you, and the surrounding code.

Comment: LatestNews and url regular expression code is taken from official doc of django. It is just need to replace LatestNewsFees to LatestNews this is it

Comment: Well, if it is truly just that, it should work. The error given on that line means there is a problem with a constructor, and `LatestNews` is the only object being constructed on that line. I see no other possible cause. Maybe someone else will see it.

Comment: another thing. This code was working fine before I changed in django admin area in section sites: localhost to public server. Becouse generated feed was linked to localhost but after i did change it doesnot work at all.

Comment: that's a lot i found problem. i put LatestEntryNews into file feeds.py which is same as feeds.py in feed package of django.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/syndication/#initialization) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/syndication/#publishing-atom-and-rss-feeds-in-tandem) these feed classes aren't meant as views. They are meant to be passed to the view `django.contrib.syndication.views.feed` as an argument.